# Create a Index List of all Sheets with their name in ListObject table column

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I want to create a index list of all sheets with their names in a table column.

So far I have written the below code but it gives an error on a quoted line.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, i As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("Profile Management")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("sheets")
With tbl.ListRows
Do While .Count >= 1
.Item(1).Delete
Loop
End With

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
"tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange = Sheets(i).Name"
Next I
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: `DataBodyRange` is a Range object whereas `Sheets(i).Name` is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with structured (aka *ListObject*) tables brings some additional concerns to VBA. You cannot write to the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) that way and the .DataBodyRane is a member of the [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx), not the ListObject's [ListColumns property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175673.aspx).

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqwe()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, i As Long, w As Long

    With Worksheets("Profile Management")
        With .ListObjects("sheets")
            'make sure there is at least 1 row in the databodyrange
            If .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then _
                .ListRows.Add
            'clear the first column
            .DataBodyRange.Columns(1).ClearContents
            'insert the worksheet names
            For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                'except "Profile Management"
                If Worksheets(w).Name <> .Parent.Name Then
                    i = i + 1
                    'expand the table for new worksheets
                    .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets(w).Name
                    'optionally insert a hyperlink to each worksheet's A1
                    .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1), _
                        Address:=vbNullString, SubAddress:=Worksheets(w).Name & "!A1", _
                        TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(w).Name, ScreenTip:="click to go there"
                End If
            Next w
            'reshape the table if there are blank rows
            Do While i < .ListRows.Count
                .ListRows(i + 1).Delete
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

As noted in comments above, I've added the option to hyperlink to each worksheet directly from its listing in the table. If you choose this route, you do not have to put the name into the table cell first.

Comment: @ Jeeped, Your code works fine but a small problem is there. If the column is empty, then it shows an error "with object variable not set". Kindly suggest.

Comment: I've added a safety to ensure there is at least one row in the databodyrange

Answer (score 1):

The following is much simpler.

```
    Sub GetWorksheetNames()
        Dim i As Long



        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profile Management").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Worksheet Inventory"
        For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profile Management").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
        Next i
    End Sub
```